# Is the flow in a centrifugal pump always constant?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pumps

Found a model for a simulated centrifugal pump in the paper of Lewin:

[Lewin,1993](http://ac.els-cdn.com/096706619500015M/1-s2.0-096706619500015M-main.pdf?_tid=bb9b04d0-441b-11e6-89e2-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1467879838_27ac1eebc37201611d63caf374d4736e)

My question arises in the simulation study the author is doing on pages 419/420.
He assumes that the pressure of the pump is given by
$$P=30+k2*F^2,$$
where $F$ is the water flow and $k2$ a time-varying resistance paramter.
Is in such a model assumed that the flow $F$ is constant?
I was wondering because considering the plot of $P$ and $F$ in **figure 4** it looks like the flow $F$ is varying with time (should be the line in the middle of the plot).

Comment: The article says: "This is because the suction line is becoming gradually plugged (as simulated by...".  See top of page 420.

Comment: yeah, but the plugging is contained in the resistance parameter $k2$, so I thought $F$ should be constant.

Comment: The flow is not constant, flow and pressure both depend on pump speed (for a given impeller etc.) and the pump will find it's working point according to the pressure on the outlet side (which depends on the downstream system) but I feel this does not help you much, something is missing from your question but I don't know what.

Comment: yeah the question is maybe a bit unspecific, the author of the paper doesn't state anything about the flow (assumed to be constant or not) and I have problems with this

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the paper. In the paper he doesn't need to know the flowrate, he is investigating ways to predict faults by measuring pressures, etc. If you're interested in characteristics of centrifugal pumps in general, you might be happier looking around for a more general introduction.